# Add embedded hyperlink to MS Access textbox in form

Tags: vba, ms-access, richtextbox

I try to do the embed a hyperlink in a textbox (rich text) in a MS Access form . Would this be possible? Didn't found any solution in the web so far...

Something like:

```
Me.TextWithLink = "Text here for link <b><a href = " & URL & "> Hyperlink Text</a></b>"
```

PS: Textbox is set to RichText, tried to set to hyperlink true/false but not working...

Is there any workaround?

Answer (score 0):

```
Form_Formular1.Text0.Value = "your text http://www.google.de"
```

Would produce automatically

[image]

As well as

```
Form_Formular1.Text0.Value = "your text <a href = ""http://www.google.de"">http://www.google.de</a>"
```

but obviously the URL and the hyperlink text needs to be the same. So

```
Form_Formular1.Text0.Value = "your text <a href = """ & url & """>" & url & "</a>"
```

Comment: got it...so it's not possible for having the URL and the hyperlink text different to "cover" long URLs with a short string, though
How this is done in other applications where the same issue is faced?

Comment: @Thinkman what other applications do you mean? Other Access applications? If yes there might be a way I don't know. If you mean non-Access applications: Well it might be possible anywhere else but not in Access.

Comment: @PEH MS Access applications, yes - i.e. use for notes taking etc. off-topic but related: interesting: HTML embedding of hyperlinks in a rich text field in a report is possible...therefore, I'm wondering if there is not a way to apply this in a form too...